# Where is my Users Account -> Advanced Tab?

Tags: windows-xp, user-management, password-management

I'm running XP Pro SP-3.
I want to manage my user network passwords as in this tab:

[image]

But for some reason when I go to my user accounts I get a different view and nowhere to get to this feature.

Comment: Is the box you are on now Home edition?

Comment: No, Proffesional

Comment: Sorry for stabbing in the dark ... any chance a local or domain GPO blocking this?

Comment: No need, any help is appreciated.
It might, I made sure that "Network access: Do not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports for network authentication" is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running 'control userpasswords2' should bring up this particular dialog. There's no "official" way to get to it that I'm aware of.

Comment: I think it depends whether the computer is configured in workgroup mode or domain mode. 'userpasswords2' is the default in domain mode, while 'userpasswords' is the default in workgroup mode.